# Android load image into variable to be used thoughtout app

Tags: android, image, android-studio, imageview, drawable

I'm using Android Developer Studio v2.2.2 and am having trouble figuring out how to load an image into a variable that can be used throughout the app. I've been trying ImageView with no success.

The following is throws a java.lang.NullPointerException

```
// At top of the class declaration
private ImageView image1;

// then in the onCreate method
image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.myImage);
```

myImage is a .png image in the res/drawable folder.

myImage exists and has been used in other spots.

I've tried doing this with Drawable and getting the same results, also getDrawable is deprecated anyways.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks...

Comment: "how to load an image into a variable that can be used throughout the app" -- it is unclear what you are gaining here. "I've been trying ImageView with no success" -- an `ImageView` is tied to its `Activity`. Unless your app has only one `Activity`, you cannot use an `ImageView` "throughout the app". "The following is throws a java.lang.NullPointerException" -- please edit your question and supply the complete Java stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources,%20int)) to load the image into a `Bitmap`.

Comment: Thanks Egor, that did it. Documentation doesn't make it clear that this replaces the deprecated getDrawable. If I could, I would give you a vote.

Comment: Well, this doesn't replace `getDrawable()`, these two methods have different return values, hence they're doing different things. The replacement for the deprecated `getDrawable()` is `ContextCompat.getDrawable()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BuddyAppAlert extends Application {
```

```html
private object obj;
public class BuddyAppAlert extends MultiDexApplication {
  obj=new Object();
}
```

create the class mentioned above, this will give you a object "obj" that exists at application level,you can then use getter and setter of this object to modify or retrieve it anywhere in your app till the app is in memory